# Table is marked as crashed and should be repaired

Tags: mysql, linux, restore

I have MySQL and Nagios installed Linux PC (Centos5.5)

I have wrote some script to fetch the data from Nagios to Mysql DB (Exactly fetch data in Table)

The data fetching working properly (confirmed with 'COUNT' cmd)

The problem when i run the following command its through error as below,

> mysql> select * from nagios_servicechecks;
>
> ERROR 1194 (HY000): Table 'nagios_servicechecks' is marked as crashed and should be repaired

Except this command, all other commands working fine.

Comment: Check this page: [Table Maintenance Statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/table-maintenance-sql.html) I guess your table uses MyISAM engine and needs `REPAIR`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Please try the below query,

```
REPAIR TABLE nagios_servicechecks;
```

Try the above query in terminal or check the below link to repair table or databases via phpmyadmin

http://php.about.com/od/mysqladministration/qt/repair_mysql.htm

Comment: correction, the quote marks are not required, and there should be a semicolon at the end, i.e.: `REPAIR TABLE nagios_servicechecks;`

Comment: @SamWatkins Thanks same has been changed..

Answer (score 0):

A nagiosxi specific method that worked for me was running their `repair_databases.sh` script found in `/usr/local/nagiosxi/scripts/`. Make sure you run it as root.